# Cambiar TextView en el archivo xml después de hacer dos solicitudes asincrónicas - Java Android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-asynctask

Hago dos solicitudes a la base de datos de Firebase y luego intento cargar los datos en el XML. Pero no los carga y simplemente deja el valor predeterminado, sospecho que es porque no manejo las solicitudes asincrónicas correctamente. ¿Alguien puede ayudarme?

```
@Override
    public View getInfoWindow(@NonNull Marker marker) {
        if (!(marker.getTitle().toString().equals("Este es mi perfil"))){
            View infoView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_info,null);
             title_mod = infoView.findViewById(R.id.title_mod);
             snipp_mod = infoView.findViewById(R.id.snipp_mod);
            imagen_mod = infoView.findViewById(R.id.imagen_mod);

            LatLng posicionMarker = marker.getPosition();
            String idLocation = String.valueOf(posicionMarker.latitude).replace(".","") + "_" + String.valueOf(posicionMarker.longitude).replace(".","");
            DataHandler dataHandler = new DataHandler();

            databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("chismesinfo");
            databaseReference.child(idLocation).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.exists()) {
                        descripcion = snapshot.child("descripcion").getValue(String.class);
                        user = snapshot.child("user").getValue(String.class);
                        firstOperation.complete(null);
                        usersReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
                        usersReference.child(user).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                                if (snapshot.exists()) {
                                    username = snapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class);
                                    if (snapshot.hasChild("profile")) {
                                        foto = snapshot.child("profile").getValue(String.class);
                                    } else {
                                        foto = null;
                                    }
                                    secondOperation.complete(null);
                                }
                            }
                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                                // Manejar errores si es necesario
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                }
            });

            if (foto != null) {
                byte[] imageAsByte = Base64.decode(foto.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsByte, 0, imageAsByte.length);
                imagen_mod.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
            title_mod.setText(username);
            snipp_mod.setText(descripcion);
            return infoView;
}
```

Esperaba que los datos se cargaran directamente en la interfaz, pero en lugar de eso, obtengo el texto de forma predeterminada.
No obstante, la segunda vez que activo el evento, carga los datos correctamente.